# Как выгрузить view из памяти

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Имеется приложение с обычным `UITabBar` с2мя `UIView`.
При переходе между вьюшками размер приложения в памяти увеличивается на ~2мб 
Будто вьюшки на заменяются, а накладываются поверх старой.

Как выгружать `UIView` когда она становится неактивной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iOS` автоматически выгружает `View` из памяти, когда это нужно, и при переходе из одного контроллера на другой кэширует их. Память могут занимать только отображаемые данные, если хранить их, например, в `@property` являющийся `NSArray of NSDictionary` - так делать не надо.

Comment: а как оптимизировать эти отображаемые данные? В коде куча пропертей типа:

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *autoNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *myBrandPickerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *itemsArray;

Comment: такие элементы как `UITextField` можно добавлять в методе `viewDidLoad` не добавляя их в `@property` 

`UITextField *field = [UITextField alloc]`
...
`[self.view addSubview:field];`

`NSArray *itemsArray` - массив уникальных id, по которым можно доставать нужные данные динамически и лучше их кешировать

Answer (score 1):

Если для ARC то:

```
UIView *view = [UIView new]; // Увеличиваем каунтер на 1
view = nil; //Уменьшаем каунтер на 1
```

Ну а раз каунтер равен 0 ARC убьет объект из памяти при первой возможности.
**UPD:** Но если вы использовали addSubview то иерархия вьюх отдельная тема. И решается через:

```
 [view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

Не надо ничего выгружать, если вы используете ARC.
Когда вы находитесь на первой вкладке, вторая вьюха еще просто не загружена (вью-контролер лиш проинициализировался). При переходе на вторую вкладку, вторая вьюха загружается в память - вот вам и прирост в 2мб.
Далее при переходе на первую вкладку, вторая вьюха выгружаться из памяти не будет (также как не выгрузилась и первая при переходе на вторую), так как загрузка вьюхи - ресурсозатратная операция и каждый раз загружать вьюху не ок.

Comment: в том то и дело, что при переходе между вьюшками каждый раз память увеличивается на 2мб. Точнее так: при переходе с 1 вью на 2ую - память увеличивается на 2 мб каждый раз. А при переходе со 2ой на 1ую вьюшку память увеличивается единожды. Значит дело в каком-то объекте, который есть во 2ой вьюшке, с утечкой памяти?

Comment: @michilly, думаю да. Только использовать слово вью в данном контексте не совсем корректно. Вы же всетаки работаете с вью-контролерами, которые передаете в таб контролер.
Скорее всего во втором контролере есть проблемный код.

Comment: к своему стыду я использую именно UIView и UITabBar. Не контроллер.

Comment: @michilly, а можно посмотреть как вы это делаете? Покажите код.

Comment: в основном все через .xib-файлы. В этом ксибе: View, в ней Navigation Bar, Tab Bar, Table View и т.д.
А переход по вкладкам через метод didSelectItem.

Comment: если в Navigation Controller загружается разный контент, то он может накапливаться. Но лучше посмотреть на код.